# adMod banner over a Static Table overwriting iAd in Swift

Tags: swift, admob, tableview, iad

I've an app with an iAd banner between static TableView and Top Bar: [image]

It was easy to do that; I simply dragged iAd banner there. Now I want to replace this banner with an adMob banner when iAd is not available.

First I tried dragging adMob banner under iAd Banner but it overwrite iAd banner.

Then I tried by code using `adMobBanner.bounds = iAdBanner.bounds` but it doesn't work too...

Is possible to do that or I just can place adMod banner somewhere else?

Comment: You don't need to place two ads, just use Admob... because it has 100% fill rate.

Comment: iAd should pay more, so i prefer iAd then, if it has no banner, I would like to use adMob...

Comment: so are you planning to hide the admob when iAd is available and vice-versa ? i mean playing with hide and show ?

Comment: Yes that's my scope. Trouble is that, in that position I can't place two different views in storyboard neither by code. My idea was to display iAd banner then, if iAd can't fill banner, create a second view over empty iAd banner an fill it with adMob banner but I can't do that and I have no idea for some alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

Here how you may do it:

1. Keep `iAd banner` in the place where you dragged it in.
2. Drag another view which is for `Admob banner` somewhere empty in the    ViewController.
3. Use the keyboard arrows to position it over `iAd banner`
4. go to "Resolve auto layout issue" in `Storyboard` and add missing constrains. and now we are done from storyboard.
5. Then in your code when iAd Banner doesn't fill,call Admob Request to fill instead.

**Update : Please backup your project before proceed **

You have to change your `TableViewController` into `View Controller` in order to customize other views in the same controller.

1. So Drag ViewController into storyboard.
2. Drag `TableView` and `TableView Cell` into your new ViewController.
3. select your `TableView` Go to Connections and connect `DataSoruce` and `Delegate` into your `View Controller`. and give `TableViewCell` an identity name.
4. Keep space for your IAd banner after customizing your Tableview layout.
5. Now you may have to do some changes in your Class lets say you have `TableViewController`, after your class declarations do as following :

   `class TableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate`
6. Make your new View Controller as initial view controller.
7. Delete your old `TableViewController` from `storyboard` and Run the app.

Comment: I can't do that because it's a TableView Controller!

Comment: I'm using a static TableView so `error: Illegal Configuration: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances`. I'll add this particular in the question!

Comment: @Matte.Car , you should have said from the beginning its not my fault your lack to explanation, Anyway i think you may have to convert it to none static tableview and its very simple...

Comment: Yes, sorry, my fault: I forget to tell it! I will keep trying some alternatives then, if they all fall, I'll consider to migrate to dynamic table, thank you!